# Get operation result in dataframe each specific row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data with 44 rows x 4 column. I want to sum and divide each 11 rows, but In my function my mistake is that I calculate the sum and the division in a whole row.

Please suggest me the simplest solution, maybe using iteration in dataframe ?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2],
                     'B':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,2],
                     'C':[7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,1,3,5,4],
                     'D':[1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3]}
                    )


a = data[['A','B','C','D']].sum()
b = data[['A','B','C','D']] / a

data_div = b.round(4)
```

Here is an example of what I expect. In the figure below I sum and divide each 4 rows in column `A`

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by doing sum and division each 11 rows? Aren't there 44 rows?

Comment: so, I want operate sum function and division in range 0-10, 11-22, 33-44. But my code I operate in range 0-44

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks like what you expect:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2],
                 'B':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,2],
                 'C':[7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,1,3,5,4],
                 'D':[1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3]}
                )


chunk_len = 11
result = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(4):
    res = data[i*chunk_len:(i+1)*chunk_len]/data[i*chunk_len:(i+1)*chunk_len].sum()
    if result.empty:
        result = res
    else:
        result = result.append(res)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as I expected. Could you modify so the return become new dataframe ?

Comment: you mean 2 dataframes? caus' sums and divs are quite diffrent data.will you describe the structure?

Comment: no, just the last operation `(data[i*chunk_len:(i+1)*chunk_len]/sum_11 )`

Comment: hey, your code can't handle if the data isn't 44 rows, I think change `for i in range(4):` become more dynamic by `for i in range(len(data.index)/11):` Maybe ?

Comment: then it would be `for i in range(len(data.index)//11)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your questions correctly, you want to sum your dataframe in groups of 11 rows. One way to do so would be:

```
result = data.iloc[0:11].sum().sum()
```

The first .sum() returns the sum of the first 10 rows divided by column, and the second sums up those sums to get the total sum. For different slices of the dataframe you would change the row choice by putting in your desired slice (like data.iloc[11:23] etc.).

The exact same logic would apply for division as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to groupby every `N` rows and then apply the sum:

```
df.index = [i // 7  for i in range(len(df))]
df['sum_A'] = df["A"].groupby(df.index).sum()
df['div_A'] = df["A"] / df['sum_A']
```

Full code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2],
                    'B':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,2],
                    'C':[7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,1,3,5,4],
                    'D':[1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3]}
                    )

df.index = [i // 11  for i in range(len(df))]     # Define new index for groupby
df['sum_A'] = df["A"].groupby(df.index).sum()     # Apply sum per group
df['div_A'] = df["A"] / df['sum_A']               # Divide each row by the given sum
print(df)
#    A  B  C  D  sum_A     div_A
# 0  1  4  7  1     22  0.045455
# 0  2  5  8  3     22  0.090909
# 0  3  6  9  5     22  0.136364
# 0  1  4  7  1     22  0.045455
# 0  2  5  8  3     22  0.090909
# 0  3  6  9  5     22  0.136364
# 0  1  4  7  1     22  0.045455
# 0  2  5  8  3     22  0.090909
# 0  3  6  9  5     22  0.136364
# 0  2  1  4  4     22  0.090909
# 0  2  1  2  1     22  0.090909
# 1  4  1  2  7     47  0.085106
# 1  5  3  3  8     47  0.106383
# 1  6  5  2  9     47  0.127660
# 1  4  1  2  7     47  0.085106
# 1  5  3  4  8     47  0.106383
# 1  6  5  5  9     47  0.127660
# 1  4  1  6  7     47  0.085106
# 1  5  3  4  8     47  0.106383
# 1  6  5  3  9     47  0.127660
# 1  1  4  6  4     47  0.021277
# 1  1  1  3  2     47  0.021277
# 2  1  4  9  7     32  0.031250
# 2  3  5  7  8     32  0.093750
# 2  5  6  8  9     32  0.156250
# 2  1  1  9  7     32  0.031250
# 2  3  1  4  8     32  0.093750
# 2  5  1  2  9     32  0.156250
# 2  1  3  7  7     32  0.031250
# 2  3  5  8  8     32  0.093750
# 2  5  1  9  9     32  0.156250
# 2  4  3  7  4     32  0.125000
# 2  1  6  8  2     32  0.031250
# 3  7  3  9  2     78  0.089744
# 3  8  9  7  3     78  0.102564
# 3  9  7  8  2     78  0.115385
# 3  7  8  9  2     78  0.089744
# 3  8  9  4  4     78  0.102564
# 3  9  4  2  5     78  0.115385
# 3  7  2  2  6     78  0.089744
# 3  8  7  1  4     78  0.102564
# 3  9  8  3  3     78  0.115385
# 3  4  9  5  6     78  0.051282
# 3  2  2  4  3     78  0.025641
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thank you, by modify index data it become more easier